# how can we declare a variable in cursor in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to store the result of fetch into a variable how we can do that in postgresql?

I also tried by creating a function it isn't working

code :

```
begin work;

DECLARE 

    cur_films CURSOR
       FOR select CURRENT_DATE + i date_
       FROM  generate_series(date '2019-11-11'- CURRENT_DATE,  date '2019-11-15' - CURRENT_DATE ) i;
       fetch forward 2 from cur_films;

close cur_films;

commit work;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am writing the query in  postgres

Comment: Why do you think you need to store the result of a cursor (select) into a variable? What is the actual, underlying problem you are trying to solve? Assuming you could do that what would you then do with those values? How would you use the variable?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am new to postgres , i actually want to pass the value obtained from cursor to a  procedure as a parameter. for testing purpose i am creating this.

Comment: That sounds like a really strange thing to do. You could store the result of the query in an array, then pass that array to your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass all values generated by your query to a function or procedure, you can aggregate everything into an array, then pass that array to the function:

```
DECLARE 
  l_dates date[];
begin
  select array_agg(g.dt::date)
    into l_dates
  from generate_series(date '2019-11-11',  date '2019-11-15', interval '1 day') as g(dt);

  perform your_function(l_dates);
end;
```

But you wouldn't need PL/pgSQL for that. This can also be done in plain SQL:

```sql
with input as (      
  select array_agg(g.dt::date) as dates
  from generate_series(date '2019-11-11',  date '2019-11-15', interval '1 day') as g(dt)
)
select *
from your_function((select dates from input));
```